# position element off the page and then retrieve position()

Tags: jquery

When I set a div element to be off the page using css and I then do a position check in a mouseMove event it returns as null.

```
this.el.css({top: '-200px', left: '-200px'});

getElementPosition:function(){
  var position = this.el.position();
  console.log(position.left) // returns null
}
```

Is there a way to move the element off the stage and then gets its position using the position() method without throwing an null

Comment: is `el` actually attached to the document? What are you `mousemove`ing over?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is. Open your console and see the results here: http://jsfiddle.net/tt2XT/

It works as expected.

Comment: I'm stupid I had removed the element by mistake. I need some sleep. Thanks again